# phonegap : javascript add multiple checkbox and radio based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, checkbox

I am new to phonegap and I wish to do the following:

```
create a screen with list options like :
```

- checkbox
- radio
- comment

Now when user selects `checkbox` , a screen should appear that has space to enter question and has 4 checkboxes and space to enter their value as answer. Also apart from 4 default checkboxes, there should be an option to `add more checkbox`.

If user selects radio, then same should happen for radio- but instead of checkbox, radio should appear.

On comment selection, - textarea should appear for answer.

Consider this as an app for survey and I wish to create questions for survey.

How do i do this using javascript? i.e. add checkboxes, radios, textarea, etc based on user selection?

Comment: Wat have u tried so far ????

Comment: i ll post it in some time, till then can you please let me know how do i change input text type to div using javascript?

Comment: How abt show nd hide make use of jquery ur task will be done easily